# Update Manager, Software Center, Synaptic Package Manager segfault

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, playonlinux

I made and ran a shell script made up of the following:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt  /sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

However, the installation failed. Since then I cant run any of Update Manager, Software Center, Synaptic Package Manager, they all segfault. None of the `apt-get` commands return any error messages nor do anything else.

Should I try and delete: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` directory? It still has `playonlinux.list.save`, `playonlinux.list` files in it. Something must be corrupted, just dont know what since I get no specific error messages via bash.

Would appreciate any help, really don't want to reinstall.

---

Okay so after:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -o APT::Cache-Start=100000000
```

I can run software-center again it doesn't crash

```
laarson@laarson-EP31-DS3L:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -o APT::Cache-Start=100000000 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp-gmic whoopsie
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,893 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu/ precise/main gimp-gmic i386 1:1.5.8.6.1-0precise0~ppa [1,867 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main whoopsie i386 0.1.34 [26.2 kB]
Fetched 1,893 kB in 2s (712 kB/s)                                                     
(Reading database ... 633686 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace whoopsie 0.1.33 (using .../whoopsie_0.1.34_i386.deb) ...
whoopsie stop/waiting
Unpacking replacement whoopsie ...
Preparing to replace gimp-gmic 1:1.5.8.6-0precise0~ppa (using .../gimp-gmic_1%3a1.5.8.6.1-0precise0~ppa_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gimp-gmic ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up whoopsie (0.1.34) ...
whoopsie start/running, process 4358
Setting up gimp-gmic (1:1.5.8.6.1-0precise0~ppa) ...
```

update-manager does run aswell

I still get some weirdness as update-manager did crash again.
The update manager does crash when trying to get info from network.

So when ever i run update or upgrade in bash with `-o APT::Cache-Start=100000000` it seems it makes segfault gone.

Without it sudo apt-get update does give the errors again. what is going on?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209984

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` shouldn't be a directory; it should be a file.

Start by deleting that directory/file. Then, correct the second line of your script; it should be `sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` (no space in-between).

On another note, if you aren't doing a batch install or something, you could just add it through Software Sources and get rid of some of the risk.

Comment: thank you for you answer. After some more research i do get:    laarson-EP31-DS3L kernel: [  175.082173] apt-check[2778]: segfault at b5d2ccb4 ip 007a6b51 sp bfb64740 error 6 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[6d1000+124000]
laarson-EP31-DS3L kernel: [  176.359893] aptd[2812]: segfault at b5de5cb4 ip 06934b51 sp bf97f060 error 6 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[685f000+124000]                              kernel: [  324.316111] apt-get[3229]: segfault at b5f22cb4 ip 00aa0b51 sp bfbcac00 error 6 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[9cb000+124000]